# How to cite the C# Language Specification Version 5.0

Tags: style, citations

I'm currently working on my thesis and need to cite a specific section of the C# Language Specification Version 5.0.

The specification is available [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029), but I can't find the authors and the publisher of the specification and so I don't know how to cite it correctly.

Until version 2.0, it had been an ECMA standard (available [here](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-334.htm)), but it [seems](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Chapter1/Specifications.aspx) that this is not true for versions 3.0-5.0.

Is it even possible to cite it? If yes, who are the authors and the publisher?

**EDIT:**
In my school there is not a strict style guideline, but for citations it's common to use the [Harvard citation style](http://guides.is.uwa.edu.au/harvard).

Comment: Welcome to Writers! Does your school use MLA/APA/other style guide or have an internal style sheet/citation formatting guide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specifications fall under the same clause as [standards](http://guides.is.uwa.edu.au/content.php?pid=43218&sid=381007) (regardless of whether they are official standards or failed to acquire such a status). In your case, it's a standard retrieved from a database.

> Identifying elements such as patent/standard numbers should be included
>
> If no individual author is available, a corporate author can be used in the in-text reference

---

> In-Text Citation:
>
> (Standards Australia 1994)
>
> Reference List Entry:
>
> Standards Australia 2008, *Personal floatation devices - General requirements.* AS 4758.1-2008. Available from: Standards Australia Online. [1 December 2008].

---

In your case, you have no author but a corporate entity: **© 1999-2012 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.** The 'Details' entry on the download page gives: **Date Published: 6/7/2013**

An in-text citation would be:

> (Microsoft Corporation 2013)

The Reference List Entry for, say, referencing the `true` and `false` literals, would look like:

> Microsoft Corporation, *C# Language Specification Version 5.0: chapter 2.4.4.1 Boolean literals.* Available from: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029 [7 June 2013]